# Why Geoserver GWC REST put tiles into strange folders?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geowebcache

I make a GWC layer, and cache it using web interface. It puts the generated tiles in folders like:

```
gwc\temp3_layer_013D0001B7ED\EPSG_900913_11
```

After I want to `reseed` this layer using Geoserver REST Api. My request:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml"
--data "<seedRequest>
          <name>temp3:layer_013D0001B7ED</name>
          <bounds>
            <coords>
              <double>6708811.26601302</double> 
              <double>7677533.00995435</double>
              <double>6780820.92578184</double>
              <double>7753033.15577275</double>
            </coords>
          </bounds>
          <gridSetId>EPSG:900913</gridSetId>
          <zoomStart>10</zoomStart>
          <zoomStop>16</zoomStop>
          <format>image/png</format>
          <type>reseed</type>
          <threadCount>2</threadCount>
          <parameters>
            <entry>
              <string>STYLES</string>
              <string>style_013D0001B7ED</string>
            </entry>
          </parameters>
        </seedRequest>" 
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/temp3:layer_013D0001B7ED.xml"
```

But after `reseed` ends I do not see expected changes in gwc layer. In gwc folder I notice that `REST` request generate new folders like:

```
gwc\temp3_layer_013D0001B7ED\EPSG_900913_11_ae1eefd6f3b22d886816cc745224e69c74ebfde9
```

Why is this happening? And how to do reseed correctly?

Comment: How did you create the layer? Name "temp3_layer_013D0001B7ED" makes me think that it is not a standard layer like topp:states that comes with the demo data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWC can create multiple caches based on the layer allowed parameters, one per parameter combination (so there is a potential for a combinatoric explosion if you allow several parameters, each combination giving birth to a different hash which gets appended to the path containing the tiles, as you can see).

In that seed request you are specifying a style, which is allowed as a parameter by default. If all you want to do is to cache with the default style, remove it from the layer configuration, and from your seeding request.

Comment: This is solution. I deleted whole `parameter` section from xml and `GWC` reseed tiles in my old folders.